# Pulumi Auto Scaling Scheduled Given start time is in the past status code: 400

Tags: amazon-ec2, pulumi

Recently, I manually removed the Auto Scaling schedule because I wasn't using it anymore. I tried to update my Pulumi script, and now I can't run it anymore because it's showing the error below. I attempted to recreate the schedule, but the error still persists.

```
Diagnostics:
  aws:autoscaling:Schedule (ecsStart):
    error: 1 error occurred:
        * updating urn:pulumi:nonprod::app-ecs::aws:autoscaling/schedule:Schedule::ecsStart: 1 error occurred:
        * creating Auto Scaling Scheduled Action (ecs-dev-apps-start): ValidationError: Given start time is in the past
        status code: 400, request id: c629be28-3f4d-47b5-a02c-9af61c4a3edc
```

Any idea on how to resolve this?

attempted to recreate the schedule, but the error still persists.